# Include tcl.h into C project

Tags: c, visual-studio, sqlite, header, tcl

I need to use tcl.h in my C project (VS 2012) for registering function in SQLite. I have downloaded Tcl for windows and installed it. But my project still doesn't recognize when I write #include . What should I do to get access to this header?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you using your includes? `#include <tcl.h>` or `#include "tcl.h"`? Also, in your project, did you add it in the properties (Additional include directories)?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added it into Additional include directories and it helped!

Comment: I've posted a more complete answer - you might need to link it to some lib - you will notice when some linker errors happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your project, go to properties, go to C/C++ session. On the field **Additional Include Directories**, add the path to the header you want, and use the header with "".

After that, you should go to the Linker session. On General, go to the **Additional Library directories** and add the path to the libs you need to add. Then go to **Input** and add the lib.

Sometimes you will need to copy a dll to the same folder of your executable. You can do that on *Custom Build Step - Post Build Events*.

You need to do it for each configuration and platform you want to build - one tip to make it easier is to use those variables *$(Configuration)* and *$(Platform)* when you are specifying the paths, and select on the dropdown list of the top of the properties window *All configurations* and *All platforms*, so you don't need to do it several times per project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Open the project properties and do :

[image: Project properties page]

Comment: Thanks for answer! This helped me